# Slider value changes on slide but not on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a slider on a Wordpress website, it's custom code not a plugin. When I slide the slider, the value changes, but when I click, nothing happens. I would like the slider to work when sliding or clicking.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery("#ex1").slider();
jQuery("#ex1").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    var pret = jQuery("#pret").val();
    var mois = slideEvt.value;
    var final = 0
    var annee = 0
    var nbmois = 0
    var pretlong = false

    if(mois>12){
        nbmois = mois%12
        final = pret*1.039
        annee = mois/12
        annee = Math.floor(annee)
        pretlong = true
        console.log(annee)
    }else
        final=pret

    final = final / mois
    console.log(pret)
    console.log(mois)
    console.log(final)

    if(pretlong)
        jQuery("#mois").text(mois+" mois (soit "+annee+" an(s) et "+nbmois+" mois)");
    else
        jQuery("#mois").text(mois+" mois");

    jQuery("#montant").text(final.toFixed(2) + "€ TTC sur "+mois+" mois");
});
```

I'd be grateful if you could help me out. Here is the link where it appears. http://www.smf-services.fr/habitat/simulateur-financement/

Comment: By the way the library is Bootstrap slider.

Comment: Can you provide the link for the library?

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider thanks for your help!

Comment: Try changing `jQuery("#ex1").on("slide", `... to `jQuery("#ex1").on("change", `

Comment: I tried that but it didn't quite work, instead, I managed using this:
    `var slide = jQuery("#ex1").slider();
    jQuery("#ex1").on("change", function(slideEvt) {
    var pret = jQuery("#pret").val();
    var mois = slide.slider("getValue");`

Comment: the slider works fine on click as well as slides in this  http://www.smf-services.fr/habitat/simulateur-financement/

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any official way of doing this [Atleast I haven't found one] IMHO. But, you can make use of **[`change event`](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#events)** of the plugin and move your update code into a separate `function`, where you pass the value to `update` and call the function on both `change` and `slide` event. `change` event will have a parameter which has value property as `object`. This object contains `old value` and `new value`, which you can make use of. Consider below example.

```
jQuery("#ex1").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    //moved code from here into a separate function below named updateValue
    //which accepts value as parameter
    updateValue(slideEvt.value);//call the function
}).on('change', function(val) {
    //val parameter above has value object which contains newValue 
    updateValue(val.value.newValue);
});

function updateValue(value) {
    var pret = jQuery("#pret").val();
    var mois = value;
    var final = 0
    var annee = 0
    var nbmois = 0
    var pretlong = false
    if (mois > 12) {
        nbmois = mois % 12
        final = pret * 1.039
        annee = mois / 12
        annee = Math.floor(annee)
        pretlong = true
    } else
        final = pret
    final = final / mois
    if (pretlong)
        jQuery("#mois").text(mois + " mois (soit " + annee + " an(s) et " + nbmois + " mois)");
    else
        jQuery("#mois").text(mois + " mois");

    jQuery("#montant").text(final.toFixed(2) + "€ TTC sur " + mois + " mois");

}
```

## [`DEMO HERE`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/heotqcnk/1/)